# Why do AIC and BIC show inversed outputs?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, interpretation, aic, bic

I am comparing three relatively simple GLMs having a Gamma distribution with AIC and BIC. The aim is to identify the effects of fertilizers (fdung), year and site on biomass of a specific grass species. Hence, the aim is not to predict new values but merely to identify the effects of the three factors.

Here are the models used:

```
res1 <-  glm((Biomass..g.m².) ~  fdung * fyear * fblock, family=Gamma(link="identity"))
res2 <-  glm((Biomass..g.m².) ~  fdung * fyear + fblock, family=Gamma(link="identity"))
res3 <-  glm((Biomass..g.m².) ~  fdung + fyear + fblock, family=Gamma(link="identity"))
```

I expect the third model to be the most simplistic one and want to confirm this by an information criterion. However, when looking at AIC and BIC I get this output.

```
AIC(res1,res2,res3)     BIC(result1,res2,res3)
        df      AIC            df      BIC
res1    49 5271.617     res1   49 5465.198
res2    16 5334.234     res2   16 5397.44
res3    10 5331.253     res3   10 5370.760
```

For AIC, the most complex model is "best" and for BIC the one with fewest df is best. I am thinking that with regard to my aim (identify effects on biomass) I should trust BIC.

Am I wrong here with my conclusion?

I already tried mixed effect models with the fblock as random factor but then the model with the Gamma distribution did not work any more and also I could not use fblock as fixed effect any more (leading to NAs for fblock), but this is not part of my question.

Comment: How many observations do you have? Manual: BIC is defined as AIC(object, ..., k = log(nobs(object)))

Comment: Are `result1` and `res1` in `AIC` and `BIC` different results in your notation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

AIC and BIC both penalize models for complexity, but they impose different penalties.

- AIC = $2k - 2 \log(L)$  where $k$ is number of parameters and $L$ is likelihood.
- BIC = $k*\log(n) - 2\log(L)$ where $n$ is number of subjects.

So, if $\log(n) > 2$, BIC penalizes more severely; this is pretty much always the case, since $e^2 = 7.3$ and it's rare to have less than 8 subjects.

As to which to use - there's debate about it; see e.g. Burnham and Anderson, *2002 Model Selection and Multimodel Inference* (a good book); they also have an article about the comparison in [Sociological Methods and Research](http://www.sortie-nd.org/lme/Statistical%20Papers/Burnham_and_Anderson_2004_Multimodel_Inference.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

My two cents on this topic: if you are really testing hypotheses then I would *not* use information theoretic approaches, but rather classical hypothesis testing approaches (i.e., I would use `drop1` on `res1` to do likelihood ratio tests).  I personally prefer AIC to BIC in ecology because I think its logic more closely matches what we think about the systems: http://emdbolker.wikidot.com/blog:aic-vs-bic . But if I find myself trying to pick the model that most closely matches a "true" model with some number of non-zero parameters, I would hypothesis-test instead.